# How to add refresh option in mate desktop environment

Tags: debian, mate, parrot-os, mate-desktop

Im trying to add the refresh button like we have in Windows in right click in mate desktop. Im running Parrot OS.

```sh
apt-get install nautilus-refresh
sudo apt-get install python-nautilus xautomation wget
```

Both these commands return error as not found,I also tried to add repository to sources.list but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to add refresh option to nautilus which is part of gnome environment whereas parrot-os uses caja which is part of mate environment

To add a working refresh option in mate, you need to:

1. Install `xautomation` by `sudo apt install xautomation` (you will need `xte` feature provided by it)
2. Now open location `/home/USER/.config/caja/scripts` folder (press `ctrl+h` in home folder to see `.config` folder)
3. Create a file named `refresh` and add the following in it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

xte "key F5"
```

4. Finally right click `refresh` file, go to `properties` and check all `Execute` options inside `Permissions` tab

You can now see a refresh option when you right click inside `scripts -> refresh`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to add the refresh button. I also added other useful scripts for clearing cache and stuff. But is there a workaround to clicking the "scripts" and then the Refresh script?

Comment: @EbenezerIsaac You can try to tweak files in `/usr/share/caja/ui` but making script is the general way to go

Comment: I don't see, how a script is ackowledged as button, although it is within the context menu. If you really want context menu "buttons", you should go with `caja-actions`. They are highly customizeable.